# Override Built-in Principal Bean

Tags: java-ee-6, cdi

In Java EE 6, there is a built in bean type `javax.security.Principal` which is available for injection like `@Inject Principal principal;`.

This is by default and I'm wondering if there is a way to change it, say, by supplying a producer method instead.

As it stands, writing a producer method will cause a deployment exception.

Example Producer:

```
my.package;

import javax.security.Principal;

public class MyProducer {

    ...

    @Produces
    public Principal obtainPrincipal() {
        return getMyPrincipal();
    }
}
```

The exception:

```
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001409 Ambiguous dependencies for type [Principal] with qualifiers [@Default] at injection point [[parameter 1] of [constructor] @Inject public my.package.MyType(Principal, SomeOtherType)]. Possible dependencies [[Producer Method [Principal] with qualifiers [@Any @Default] declared as [[method] @Produces @SessionScoped protected my.package.MyProducer.obtainPrincipal()], Built-in Bean [java.security.Principal] with qualifiers [@Default]]]
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:278)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:244)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBean(Validator.java:107)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateRIBean(Validator.java:127)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBeans(Validator.java:346)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateDeployment(Validator.java:331)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.validateBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:366)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.WeldContainer.start(WeldContainer.java:83)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.services.WeldService.start(WeldService.java:76)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

So the question is - is there any way to replace the default built in types in CDI?

To give you an idea of why I need this, my project is switching from JAAS to Apache Shiro. There is a good amount of existing code that does something based on the injected principal. Shiro in a web environment however, only wraps the HttpServlet request / response and overrides the appropriate security related methods. That however does not propagate to CDI, which in that case always returns the anonymous principal.

**Update**
I also tried the following:

```
my.package;

import javax.security.Principal;

@Alternative
public class MyPrincipal implements Principal {


    ...

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return getMyPrincipalName();
    }

}
```

Then enabling the alternative in beans.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaeehttp://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_0.xsd">

    <alternatives>
        <class>my.package.MyPrincipal</class>
    </alternatives>

</beans>
```

In this case, there are no deployment errors, but the injected principal is still the default one, not my enabled alternative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The guys at Weld helped me out. My deployment structure was something like:

```
-- app.war
  |-- module0.jar (beans.xml)
  |-- module1.jar (beans.xml)
  |-- ...
  |-- other-lib.jar
```

But in CDI 1.0, alternatives are anabled per bean archive only. So, adding

```
<alternatives>
    <class>my.package.MyPrincipal</class>
</alternatives>
```

in each beans.xml makes it all work.